# Should I place a full page background image in a react component?

Tags: css, reactjs, background-image

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm looking to create a full screen background image for my site, yet I can't figure out if I should place the image in **1)** the index.html file (outside of any React components), **2)** inside the main App component (the highest parent component), or **3)** one level deeper: a component inside the main App component.

Not sure if this makes sense? Let me know if you have any clarifying questions. I've search a ton online, but haven't found any solid answers.

I've also attached an image with a general idea of what I'm looking to create.

Thank you!

*The file structure I'm working with was created with create-react-app. I know I probably don't need to use React for the site pictured below, but it's for practice.

[image: Page mockup]

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Unless the background image is static, you will probably want a `BackgroundImage` component that knows how to pick the image to display. Said component might also need to contain styles for scaling, etc. Assuming that it may need props from `App` to function, probably should be a child of `App`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the image serves as background to all components you plan to render, just add it to the `index.html` page, or more properly, add something like the following to `index.css` and import it into `index.js`

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  /** background image */
  background-image: url("./img/background.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```