# How to make an image full screen background image and change it via button in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

this probably has answer somewhere but it took so much time from me. My problem is so similar to here [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54334225/should-i-place-a-full-page-background-image-in-a-react-component). Based on button click I want to fetch a new image url and change background image dynamically. So basically there will be a input box, button and background image.

I am very beginner with css and what I want is that input, button and icon are being shown in the center of the page and background image as fullscreen. Functionality is done but I couldnt get done the appearance.

Here is what I did so far:

```
// App.js

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Background></Background>
          <City />
          <WeatherCard />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And backgroud component.

```
// Background.js

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    bgImage: {
      /* Full height */
      height: "100vh",

      /* Center and scale the image nicely */
      backgroundPosition: "center",
      backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
      backgroundSize: "cover",

    },
  });

  const Background = () => {
    const store = useSelector((store) => store);
    const classes = useStyles();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    return (
      <div
        className={classes.bgImage}
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url("some url")`,
        }}
      ></div>
    );
  };

  export default Background;
```

This is what i get[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to bgImage class.

```
position: "relative",
display: "flex",
justifyContent: "center",
alignItems: "center",
zIndex: -1
```

Input box and button as children of the div element as follows.

```
<div
    className={classes.bgImage}
    style={{
     backgroundImage: `url("some url")`,
    }}
>
    <input type="text" />
    <button type="button">button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried to design everything as a react component. Background has bacgkround image and correspond css as shown above. Button and input box are also a react component. So when I put City and WeatherCard component child of Background, I only see background image, not other components

Comment: Can you reproduce it on codesandbox.io or something similar? Also, try giving a lower z index to the div element and relatively higher z index to the children

Comment: I have edited the answer to change the CSS properties to resemble javascript object (as used in react) and added alignItems and zIndex properties